# How to create custom report in PDF using matplotlib and python

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am working on a project where i have to present the Chart /graph created using matplotlib with python3 into a PDF format. The PDF must carry the data, custom titles along with the chart/graph. PDF can be multiple page report as well. I know that we can store the matplotlib charts in PDF. But i am looking for any solution if we can achieve Data, chart and custom text in PDF format.

Comment: Please post the code that you already tried (minimized so that it works without other things that aren't related) So we can help you better. Please take a look at: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Matplotlib allows to put text and tables in figures and to save figures to pdf. So I think it's not very clear what you're asking for here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What my intention is creation a report in PDF format that should have the Chart crated with matplotlib and also able to write some custom data/ text in it..I know matplotlib has functions to save the chart ALONE in pdf format. BTB, I came across a library called reportlab that can be used for the purpose. I will share once i explore that. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried reportlab and able to write the chat in PDF. Thanks eveyone

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is not very clear. If I have to do what I understand from your question, I will use Jupyter Notebook and save it as PDF. In this notebook, I will have:

- Exploratory analysis of the data (What data scientists call EDA)
- Discussion and other mathematical formulas at they may apply to your case
- The plots

You can save jupyter notebooks to PDF using `nbconvert` module in Python.
If you don't have it installed on your computer, do so with this command: 
`pip install nbconvert`

To save your notebook as a PDF, go to the folder containing your Jupyter notebook file and run the following command:

`jupyter nbconvert --to pdf MyNotebook.ipynb`

Comment: I am sorry for insufficient detail provided. However my exact question has been explained in the above comment. Thank you for your response.